# How can I decode CP852 to UTF-8 in node.js?

Tags: node.js, utf-8, decode

Is there any way to convert text from CP852 to UTF-8 in node or in client webpage?

Answer (score 3):

It should be possible with [`iconv`](https://npmjs.org/package/iconv):

```
var iconv = require('iconv');
var cp852 = new iconv.Iconv('CP852', 'UTF-8');

// based on http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page_852
// Ç (U+00C7), É (U+00C9), á (U+00E1), and ░ (U+2591)
var input = new Buffer([ 128, 144, 160, 176 ]);

console.log(cp852.convert(input));
```

Or you might try [`iconv-lite`](https://npmjs.org/package/iconv-lite):

```
var iconv = require('iconv-lite');

var input = new Buffer([ 128, 144, 160, 176 ]);

console.log(iconv.decode(input, 'cp852'));
```

Comment: Forgot to say that i want it running on windows and iconv dont want to install there

Comment: @KrzysztofSkowroński You should be able to install `iconv` if you have `node-gyp`'s [requirements for Windows](https://github.com/TooTallNate/node-gyp#installation). Otherwise, you can try [`iconv-lite`](https://npmjs.org/package/iconv-lite) (see edit for snippet).